# Stop Windows Backup from making Deduplication Exclusion for backup drive

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-backup, deduplication

With Windows Server Backup after every backup, the server puts an exclusion in the Deduplication list for the backup folder. Is there a way to stop this behavior?

If not, is there a way to get Powershell to remove the exclusion?

Edit:
The Powershell command is;

```
Set-DedupVolume -Volume Y: -ExcludeFolder {}
```

I'd prefer to prevent this behavior if possible.